# Converting 4-D numeric array to categorical

Tags: arrays, r

I have the following problem:

I have a 4D array, say, for example

```
a <- array(seq(1,2*3*4*2), c(2,3,4,2))
a[1,2,3,2] <- NaN
```

I need to convert this array to categorical data using a certain threshold. As an example it could be something like `a[ a > 10 ] <- "1"` and `a[ a <= 10 ] <- "0"`.

Now the problem is that NaN values also get converted to "0".

How could I do this?

Comment: Did you meant `a[ a > 10  & !is.nan(a)] <- 1; a[ a <= 10  & !is.nan(a)] <- 0 `

Comment: @akrun But then the data is not categorical. As soon as I `a[ a > 10 & !is.nan(a)] <- "1"` all the NaN values are converted to "1" or "0".

Comment: Or just `a[] <- as.numeric(a>10)` will do it (the `NaN` converts to `NA`)

Comment: NaN values are not converted to "1" or "0", they are converted to `"NaN"`.

Comment: Using `a[ a > 10 & !is.nan(a)] <- 1; a[ a <= 10 & !is.nan(a)] <- 0 ` does not convert the data to categorical.

Comment: The `class(NaN)#[1] "numeric"`.  A matrix can hold only a single class.  So, I don't know how you want two classes to coexist in an array.  Instead if use `NA`, `NA` can have `NA_character_` or `NA_real_`, `NA_integer_` etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal ... The first of your operations converts that `NaN` to a "NaN" which is not a `NaN`. The atomic vector underlying the array cannot hold a true `NaN` since you changed it to a character vector.

```
, , 3, 2

     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "1"  "NaN" "1" 
[2,] "1"  "1"   "1"
```

The second comparison and assignment converts to

```
, , 3, 2

     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "0"  "NaN" "0" 
[2,] "0"  "0"   "0"
```

So I'm a bit puzzled about your claim that it got converted to a "0". You might still be puzzled about what the other values got converted to zeroes, but that is explained by this operation:

```
> "1" <= 10
[1] TRUE
```

This delivers what I think you want:

```
a[] <- ifelse( is.na(a), "NaN", 
                         ifelse(a >10 , "1", "0") )
#Check
table(a, useNA="always")
#----
a
   0    1  NaN <NA> 
  10   37    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to work with integers `1` and `0` rather than characters `"1"` and `"0"` then all you need to do is

```
a[] <- as.numeric(a>10)
```

The `[]` ensures that the structure of `a` is retained - otherwise it becomes a vector.  `as.numeric` simply converts the logical `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`.  The `NaN` becomes `NA`.

You then get

```
a
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1

, , 3, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 4, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 3, 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA    1
[2,]    1    1    1

, , 4, 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
```